Cross-Origin Request Blocked, POST request blocked but get requests work fine
Springboot Restful API
Vue.js front end
When attempting a POST request, it is blocked by CORS.
heres my backend controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/gaaManagementSystem")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:5173", allowedHeaders = "*")
public class MainController {


    @Autowired
    private MemberServiceImpl memberService;

    // add new member
    @PostMapping("/member-create-account")
    public ResponseEntity<String> addMember(@RequestBody Member member){
        try {
            memberService.addNewMember(member);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Member added successfully");
        } catch (Exception e){
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Failed to add Member");
        }
    }
}

heres my front end request
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      member: {
        member_id: '',
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
        email: '',
        dob: '',
        contact_no: '',
        address1: '',
        address2: '',
        address3: '',
        club: '',
        membership_type: ''
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async submitForm() {
      try {
        await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/gaaManagementSystem/member-create-account', this.member);
        // Reset form fields after successful submission
        this.member = {
          first_name: '',
          last_name: '',
          email: '',
          dob: '',
          contact_no: '',
          address1: '',
          address2: '',
          address3: '',
          club: '',
          membership_type: ''
          // direct to members portal
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error adding member:', error);
      }
    }
  }
}

I am a student in my second year, project is due in a week so even a quick fix for now would help just to get this submitted.
What I have tried:
•   @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:", allowedHeaders = "")
•   Added a chrome extension to bypass: moesif
•   Created a new backend to test.
•   Added a corsFilter method in the application class.
•   Added a corsMapping method in the application class.
•   Tried different browsers.
•   Tried the same post method in a separate frontend project that does function correctly.
Also, Postman allows me to send a post request with no issues
I believe the problem is to do with the backend but im new to these and have no idea

Try allowedHeaders = "content-type". Axios silently includes a Content-Type: application/json header in some requests; such requests are subject to CORS preflight and require the server to explicitly allow content-type as a request-header name.
